# What does “doing press” mean in the following context?

Tags: meaning

> From this scan of Paul we were able to turn him into a 3D printable figure.
>
> Some of you may already have seen photos of the figure. Paul had them with him whilst doing press for the 'Hope For The Future' single in November, and we teased them in the December newsletter.
>
> <sub>**Source:** "[Print Your Very Own 3D Paul](http://www.paulmccartney.com/news-blogs/news/print-your-very-own-3d-paul)," a blog posting at PaulMcCartney.com</sub>

Comment: Doing press interviews and the like...

Answer (score 2):

As Tushar Raj notes in a comment above, "doing press" is evidently an informal way of saying "doing press interviews," "generating media coverage," "promoting oneself or one's product in ways that garner attention in the press and in other media for publicity purposes," or the like.